# Graphic novel about an alien prince in battle armour, who fights other aliens to prevent his species from being enslaved

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I remember the graphic novel being about a family who stumble apon a large island with tons of different creatures. However in the background, the island is actually a sleeping giant whose race was protecting another species who were being attacked.

The prince of this race wants to fight, but his dad says no, so an evil alien tricks the prince by saying he will turn on the prince's battle armour, when in reality he removes the prince's movement cog and kidnaps him. The father surrenders and the race the giants were protecting and who repaired the giants is enslaved.

The prince is then sent to Earth, covered in fauna and sent to sleep, but the family bring him back to life, and he defeats the evil alien.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Comment: @senior pug - If you found the story you were looking for, you should submit it as an [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/answering) to your own question, and then mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I found the book, it's [Bad Island](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/10254690-bad-island) by Doug TenNaple

> When Reese is forced to go on a boating trip with his family, the last thing he expects is to be shipwrecked on an island-especially one teeming with weird plants and animals. But what starts out as simply a bad vacation turns into a terrible one, as the castaways must find a way to escape while dodging the island's dangerous inhabitants. With few resources and a mysterious entity on the hunt, each secret unlocked could save them . . . or spell their doom. One thing Reese knows for sure: This is one Bad Island.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could greatly improve upon this answer by editing it to explain why you think this is the book the OP was thinking of (i.e. how does it match the book described in the question?). Adding a synopsis from a site like Goodreads or Wikipedia, along with a link to whichever page you copied and pasted the synopsis from, would be beneficial as well.